# Incorrect routing via /config/routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following (basic) route set up in a CI-based web app:

```
$route['sms/resend/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'sms/resend/$1/$2';
```

The controller + 'resend' method:

```
class Sms extends CI_Controller {
    public function resend($to, $message) {
        // my code
    }
}
```

Logically speaking, anything that doesn't fit the route should be directed to a 404 page instead of the `resend()` method within the `sms` controller. This isn't the case, however. The following URL, for example, isn't redirected correctly, it goes to the same controller+method:

```
http://myapp/sms/resend/uuuu/WhateverMessage
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any other route that goes to the same controller ?

Comment: Just one other, yes: `$route['sms/checkoperator/(:num)'] = 'sms/resend/$1/$2';`. The same problem goes for this route too.

Comment: In what order are they defined ? and your second route has an extra param  it should be `$route['sms/checkoperator/(:num)'] = 'sms/resend/$1'`

Comment: I've corrected the second route to `$route['sms/checkoperator/(:num)'] = 'sms/checkoperator/$1'`. This route follows `route['sms/resend/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'sms/resend/$1/$2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I've come to understand that CI's default routing does not get deactivated when a default route related to a specific `controller/method` pair is added. That being said, if a URL does not fit the route `$route['sms/resend/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'sms/resend/$1/$2'`, then the same URL is run through CI's default routing mechanism as a fallback, so it still takes me to the `resend` method of the `sms` controller. To prevent this from happening, I needed to add another custom route that follows all others related to the sms resending, that redirects any other url to a different controller+method. If this controller doesn't exist, you get the default 404 page. 
So the final `/config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['sms/resend/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'sms/resend/$1/$2';
$route['sms/checkoperator/(:num)'] = 'sms/checkoperator/$1';
$route['sms/(:any)'] = 'somewhereovertherainbow';
```

Comment: That's what I said! But there is a other option, I will correct my post in some seconds

Answer (score -2):

I think the rout file is just for rerouting. Your URL don't fits the routing Conditions so it don't gets rerouted! So it goes the normal way wich is the same (in this case!)

Something like this could work!

(! :num) /(:any) ']  = error page (or not existing page)

So every request wich doesn't start with a number gets redirected to the error page!

The syntax might be wrong!

This would work great :

$route['sms/resend/[^0-9]/(:any)'] = 'errorpage';
You have to replace the error page by something ;)

Comment: Are you familiar with **[codeigniter routes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)**?

Comment: Like I said the routes.php is for rerouting! ! If the rerouting conditions in the file don't match, the URL will just load the normal controller defined in the URL. So yes I do!

Comment: @Teifun2 -- You are very much incorrect. Please take another look at [codeigniter routes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)